# How to overcome the following Error when I try to clone a git repository?

Tags: linux, git

How can I overcome the following error

fatal: unable to access 'https://gitorious.org/linux-can/can-modules.git/': gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function

I am trying to install an additional kernel module for using the ISO-TP protocol in socketcan

I have disabled my firewall in Linux using the following command

```
sudo ufw disable
```

Comment: Looks like a ssl problem. Can you *temporarily* try : `git config --global http.sslVerify false` ?

Comment: My guess is it is a temporary problem on server side. I tried reaching the website itself but I could not.

Comment: Me too — tried to open the site in two browsers at different hosts, got SSL errors.

Comment: https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/https://gitorious.org/ ­—  It's not just you! gitorious.org looks down from here.